# Meteor.js lib folder is loading but not reading on client

Tags: javascript, meteor, server

I had an issue with meteor.js

As written in documentation, lib folder is loading first of all,  [in fact, a bit not like that :C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467681/meteor-js-lib-folder-not-loaded-first)

So, my project is running succesfully, but js code is not executing automatically...

- [**here is the numerated screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUhzA.png)

1) Here I try to execute "Posts.findOne();" code, to ensure script is executed, but it's not.

2) Here we can see that script have been loaded.

3) Here I copied that script and succesfully executed, then tried again "Posts.findOne();" testing code, and it's works!

Please help to resolve that stuff. Why that's is happening?

Thank you , and have a good day!

Comment: Are you subscribing the collection on client side ?

Comment: It must be automatically subscribed, coz I'm not switched this off yet

Answer (score 0):

Snap! I'm really blind, that problem was coused by Git.
it's cloned project, so meteor was reading both, that's why this conflict appears.

Be careful and good luck everybody :D